# Callback function in Moongose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, callback

is there anyway to return a value in a function with a callback function?

```
function getnextseq(){    
 autoincrement.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:"userid"}, { $inc: { seq:1}},function(err,data){
console.log(data.seq)
})
return data.seq;
}
console.log(getnextseq());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return data.seq won't work since findOneAndUpdate is asynchrouse. You need either pass a callback function or use promise

```
function getnextseq(cb) {    
 autoincrement.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:"userid"}, { $inc: { seq:1}},function(err,data){
   cb(data.seq);
 })

}

getnextseq(function(seq) {
   console.log(seq);
 }
);
```

Or promise way

```
 function getnextseq() {    
    return autoincrement.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:"userid"}, { $inc: { seq:1}}).exec();
 }



 getnextseq().then(function(seq) {
   console.log(seq)
 });
```

Comment: how to pass this using a promise?

Comment: exec() will return a promise. I have updated my answer.